# Detect if defined id in the DOM tree is present

Tags: jquery, parent

I search for a way to detect if a JQuery click target has a parent with a defined id `$('#contextMenu')` in his DOM tree.

```js
$("html").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).parents('#contextMenu')) {
    alert('yes');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="contextMenu">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> share</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Check the `length` property. `if($(e.target).parents('#contextMenu').length)`. However `closest()` will be better performance wise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: You'd have better to delegate event, i'm guessing.. `$(document).on('click', '#contextMenu', function(){ alert('yes'); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

```
$( "html" ).click(function(e) {         
   if ($(e.target).parents('#contextMenu').length) {
      alert('yes');
   }
});
```

However [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will be better performance wise.

Thanks to [@A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff), You can use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#contextMenu', function(){ 
   alert('yes'); 
});
```

Comment: `closest` will be better only when the element has the given parent.. in which case even parents will work the same right? if closest is not found then its anyways bubbled up till the top right?

Comment: @Reddy, `closest` will stop when matching element is found where as `parents` will continue reading to top

Comment: @Satpal Ya but `closest()` includes element itself. So here it could give unexpected result

Comment: @Satpal  EDIT: i don't think it does really matter but keep comment for prosperity... ;)

Answer (score 2):

use the [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property to check if the element exist or not.

```
$( "html" ).click(function(e) {         
   if ($(e.target).parents('#contextMenu').length) {
      alert('yes');
   }
});
```

if length is 0 it means no elements found,